# How to make the cancel button work in linked sdk call in android web view?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I am working with linked in and Facebook sdk in my android app. I am getting the linked in and Facebook login details for login in my app. While the webview load the authorization page, there is a cancel button. I want, when user click on that button the webview should close or redirect to some other webpage. Same thing in Facebook Sdk also. I need help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the cancel button do at the moment?

Comment: Actually it should redirect to a url provided in the registration page. But it is not doing that also.

Comment: Based on the code that I *can't* see, I *can't* tell you what the problem is. Seek further info here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

I have got the answer. Actually while we are creating the App page on Linked in ,there will be a option to give the redirect Url. There we have to provide. After that if the cancel button is press it will redirect to that url and close the dialog